How do I look up all the instances of a word in one column and return the text from another column all into a single column if True?
I am building a teacher roster that I can use to quickly know which of my guild members are able to teach any particular class. I'm sharing the link to a sample spreadsheet.
In Col A, you can see what each person says they can teach.
In Col C, it gives the name of the teacher in question.
I would like D2 to return the names of all the teachers who said they are willing to teach figurative work, as specified in their respective rows. So, Cell D2 would say "Alison, Eva, etc."
And likewise, I will do the same for each subject, so Cell E2 will list all the people who can teach Underglaze Transfers, etc.
Thank you in advance.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bn2u5Km9CSDLrbgEvc8DEbnutrdx5JQi09OzW875jG0/edit?usp=sharing
I've tried it with Search and Vlookups, but I can't get the syntax right, and I'm not really sure how to compile all the names into cells.


You may try:
=filter(C:C,search(D1,A:A),C:C<>"")


